# How do I make myself think before I act?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, personality, motivation

How do I suppress strong emotions in favour of doing the right thing?

Comment: Since an emotional response is a neurological response, and since a neurological response is influenced by conditioning (relying on neuroplasticity), it should be expected that it would take practice to change the habit of reacting emotionally in a certain way. Personally I have found meditation to be quite helpful in this specific way -- learning to control emotional responses to both stimuli and thoughts. Avoid distractions and things that make you feel impulsive. Impulsiveness is the opposite of self-restraint.